# Prove or Disprove: $\sum_{n\geq 0} (3p^2_n - p_n - 2p^3_n) \leq 0$ for any probability mass ${\bf p} = (p_0,p_1,\ldots)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

Assume that $N \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and ${\bf p} = (p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_{2N+1})$ is a probability mass function, i.e., $p_n \geq 0$ for all $0\leq n \leq 2N+1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} p_n = 1$. For some reason, I am speculating that the following inequality holds
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} (3\,p^2_n - p_n - 2\,p^3_n) \leq 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
regardless of the choice of ${\bf p}$. I attempted many specific examples and could not find a counter-example, may I know if someone can prove the conjecture \eqref{1} or disprove my conjecture by displaying a specific counter-example?

Comment: If $f(x)=3x^2-x-2x^3$ then its obvious that $f(x)=-f(1-x)$ and that for $x \in [0,1]$ $f(x)>0$ only for $x \in [0.5,1]$. Then if some $p_i \geq 0.5$, all other $p_n$'s sum up to $1-p_i$. So, due to concativity of $f(x)$ on $[0,0.5]$ sum of $f(p_n)$'s is no more than $f(1-p_i)$, which equals $-f(p_i)$.

Comment: The $f$ is convex on $[0,0.5]$ instead of being concave

Comment: It would be nice to write down the details carefully as the appearance of a "convex combination" is still not clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give it another try.

First, note that $3p_n^2 -p_n -2p_n^3 = p_n(1-p_n)(2p_n -1)$. Then we have two possible situations: (i). All of $p_n$'s are less than or equal to $1/2$; (ii). One of them is greater than 1/2.

Case i) is trivial. Let us focus on case ii). It is sufficient to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} (3p_n^2 - 2 p_n^3) \leq 1$

Suppose $p_0 > 1/2$. Consider function $f(x) = 3x - 2x^2$. Then $f'(x) \geq 0$ in $[0, 1/2]$. Thus $f(x)$ is non-decreasing in $[0, 1/2]$. So $f(p_n) \leq f(1-p_0) = (1-p_0)(1+2p_0)$. Now

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} 3p_n^2 - 2 p_n^3 &= p_0^2 (3-2p_0) + \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} p_n f(p_n) \\
& \leq p_0^2 (3-2p_0) + \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} p_n f(1-p_0) \\
& = p_0^2 (3-2p_0) + (1-p_0) f(1-p_0) \\
& = p_0^2 (3-2p_0) + (1-p_0)^2(1+2p_0) \\
& = 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This attempt is successful! Thanks!

Comment: @FeiCao Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

One can also "bash" it by homogenizing. In other words, we need to prove that for non-negative variables $x_1,x_2,\dots x_n$:

$$3\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^3+2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3.$$
This can be expanded nicely using triple summation with Einstein/Kronecker notation. For example, the left hand side is:
$$LHS=3\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{k,j=1}^nx_kx_j\delta_{kj}=3\sum_{i,j,k=1}^nx_ix_jx_k\delta_{jk}.$$
The RHS is similarly:
$$RHS = \sum_{i,j,k=1}^nx_ix_jx_k + 2\sum_{i,j,k=1}^nx_ix_jx_k\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}.$$
Therefore, after cycling through $(j,k)\to (k,i)\to (i,j) $ and adding all three equivalent formulations, the coefficient of $x_ix_jx_k$ in the expansion of $3(LHS-RHS)$ is:
$$c_{ijk} = 3+2(\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}+2\delta_{jk}\delta_{ki}+2\delta_{ki}\delta_{ij})-3(\delta_{ij}+\delta_{jk}+\delta_{ki})\geq 0$$
which is fairly trivial to check. In fact, $c_{ijk}>0$ if and only if $i,j,k$ are pairwise distinct and otherwise zero.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer post by Yan Zhu above, there is a another (unified) way to prove it (using the same notations). Indeed, the key observation is that $$\sum_{n\geq 1} p_n\,f(p_n) \leq (1-p_0)\,f(1-p_0)$$ and this holds whether $p_0$ (maximum among the $p_n$'s) is located in $(0,\frac 12]$ or $[\frac 12,1]$. Indeed, By the concavity of $f \colon x \mapsto 3x-2x^2$ on $[0,1]$, we have
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p_n}{1-p_0}\,f(p_n) \leq f\left(\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p^2_n}{1-p_0}\right).$$ So it suffices to show that $$f\left(\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p^2_n}{1-p_0}\right) \leq f(1-p_0) \label{2}\tag{2}$$ As was noted before, $f$ is non-decrasing for $x \in [0,\frac 34]$ with and non-increasing for $x \in [\frac 34,1]$, with $f(1/2) = f(1)$. Moreover, we have $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p^2_n}{1-p_0} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p_n}{1-p_0}p_n \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} p_n = 1-p_0.$$ Thus, the inequality \eqref{2} is trivially true when $p_0 \in [\frac 12,1]$. On the other hand, when $p_0 \in (0,\frac 12]$ so that $1-p_0 \in [\frac 12,1]$, we can show that
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{p^2_n}{1-p_0} \leq 2\sum_{n\geq 1} p^2_n \leq 2p_0\sum_{n\geq 1} p_n = 2p_0(1-p_0) \leq \frac 12.$$ So the inequality \eqref{2} is still valid. This finishes the proof.